# Perl : Like in java we can access public member (variables) in other class is there any same concept in perl

Tags: perl

I have 2 perl file and i want to use value of one variable in another perl file as input so how i can do it  is there any concept like java we can declare it as public and use it.
any help appreciated thank you!

Comment: Read through http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html - although you don't need "OO" to share variables/state

Comment: You can access variables declared using `our` (instead of `my`) by fully qualifying them with the package name, such as `print $Other::Package::shared_value`, but it's an ugly thing to do. In general you should write an access method and export it to the calling code, even if your modules aren't object oriented. You should show full details of your code and the value you want to share

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I'll skip the discussion about whether it is the right decision to use OOP or not and just assume you want to do it the OOP-way.

In short, all variables of an object in Perl can be considered public. In fact, the problem is often the opposite - to make some of them private. Anyway, if you have a file `Obj.pm` which defines an object with a field `foo` which looks like this:

```
package Obj;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = {foo => "bar"};

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

you can access the `foo` variable as if it were public:

```
use Obj;

my $obj = Obj->new();
print $obj->{foo};
```

For perhaps a more pleasant OOP in Perl, look at the `Moose` package which gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

As  @user2864740 pointed you don't need "OO" in perl to share variables.It is one way, Let's say you have two files 
**Foo.pm**(package)**:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter;

package Foo;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw( blat); #exported by default
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(bar );#not exported by default

our $x="42";#variable to be shared should be "our" not "my"
sub bar { 
   print "Hello $_[0]\n" 
}

sub blat { 
print "World $_[0]\n" 
}
1;
```

Access that variable from other file as
**bar.pl** :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Foo;


print "$Foo::x";#imported variable
blat("hello");#imported subroutine
```

If you want to import listed functions then:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Foo qw(bar blat);# import listed subs


print "$Foo::x";#imported variable
blat("hello ");#imported subroutine
bar("hi");#this also get imported
```

Comment: Let me know if you want OO way,I will update but do some homework.